# How to convert class attributs of types numpy.double, numpy.single and struct.Struct to the respective numba types?

Tags: python, numpy, numba

How to convert class attributs of types numpy.double, numpy.single and struct.Struct to the respective numba types, in order to be able to use such attributes with jitclass?

1) For example one of the class attributes has the following form:

```
self.type = numpy.double
```

In order to compile a python class with such attribute I would have to map it to a numba type. I tried numba.typeof(numpy.double) but it yields the following error

```
In [1]: a=numpy.double
In [2]: numba.typeof(a)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-244-7ab9d6ba8d0a> in <module>
----> 1 numba.typeof(a)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\typing\typeof.py in typeof(val
 purpose)
     32         msg = _termcolor.errmsg(
     33             "cannot determine Numba type of %r") % (type(val),)
---> 34         raise ValueError(msg)
     35     return ty
     36

ValueError: cannot determine Numba type of <class 'type'>
```

2) in the case of using struct.Struct I get a similar error

```
In [1]: from struct import Struct
In [2]: a = Struct(">dd")
In [3]: numba.typeof(a)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-76-7ab9d6ba8d0a> in <module>
----> 1 numba.typeof(a)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\typing\typeof.py in typeof(val,
 purpose)
     32         msg = _termcolor.errmsg(
     33             "cannot determine Numba type of %r") % (type(val),)
---> 34         raise ValueError(msg)
     35     return ty
     36

ValueError: cannot determine Numba type of <class 'Struct'>
```

MINIMAL (WORKING) EXAMPLE:

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb
from struct import Struct

spec = [('type', nb.typeof(np.double)), ('h', nb.typeof(Struct(">f8")))]

@nb.jitclass(spec)
class TestClass:

    def __init__(self):
        self.type = np.double
        self.h = Struct(">f8")
```

When I try to compile the above class I get the following error:

```
C:>python classtest.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "classtest.py", line 5, in <module>
    spec = [('type', nb.typeof(np.double)), ('h', nb.typeof(Struct(">f8")))]
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\typing\typeof.py", line
 34, in typeof
    raise ValueError(msg)
ValueError: ←[1mcannot determine Numba type of <class 'type'>←[0m
```

Answer (score 0):

> How to convert class attributs of types numpy.double, numpy.single and struct.Struct to the respective numba types, in order to be able to use such attributes with jitclass?

For `numpy.double` and `numpy.single` it's easy, `numba.float64` and `numba.float32` are the corresponding numba types.

In Version 0.43.1 the `numba.typeof` also works on the NumPy types, however the function is expecting an **instance** not the class itself:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import numba as nb
>>> nb.__version__
'0.43.1'
>>> nb.typeof(np.double(10))
float64
```

However there's currently (as of version 0.43.1 of numba) no support for `struct` in numba (see ["2.6. Supported Python features" of the numba documentation](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.43.0/reference/pysupported.html)), so you cannot use `struct` with nopython mode in numba (that includes `jitclass`).

Of course you can unpack your struct into the individual components and if numba supports them use them instead. For example instead of `'dd'` you could add two `numba.float64` fields on the `jitclass`. Since you've been using different structs and not every Python type is supported in numba you may need to experiment with that.